# InvalidAddressError: invalid address when testing rollbar setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rollbar

I just setup rollbar within my rails app using the rollbar gem, but when running the rake task to test my setup it gives me this error (backtrace appended below).

```
Started GET "/verify" for  at 2017-11-07 01:29:13 +0100

IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
```

Obviously the address is empty and therefore it makes sense, the address is invalid, but i have no clue why this is the case.

The token is correctly set in the environment and within the rollbar dashboard of this project I even see the failed attempt as error.

Further Info: Rails 4.2.4 on ruby 2.2.3

Here is the backtrace, I'd be really happy for any tips!

```
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:559:in `in6_addr'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:496:in `initialize'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:514:in `new'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:514:in `coerce_other'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ipaddr.rb:170:in `include?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `block in include?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `any?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `include?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/request.rb:16:in `from_whitelited_ip?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/whiny_request.rb:8:in `from_whitelited_ip?'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rollbar-2.15.5/lib/rollbar/rake_tasks.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
from /var/www/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:335:in `exec'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/exe/bundle:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/exe/bundle:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to Rollbar's support, as it is a commercial project with dedicated support.

Comment: Probably a good idea, aswell, thank you. As I wanted to try it out first and will be using the free tier, I don't know how responsive they will be, but definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. It seems to be a semi-known issue with Rollbar: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/issues/541. I can confirm that removing the `web-console` gem (which I wasn't using anyway) from my Gemfile fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out that issue, it is completelt the same. Will try turning off web-console, but doesn't the verification and posting process rely on it in the rollbar gem?

Comment: Actually this did work, but actually I would like to keep web_console :p